# CORS allows some GET requests, but not Facebook login requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors

I'm currently trying to implement a third party authentication functionality for my website. This is an "enableCORS" function I got from the net. It is located in "Server.js".

```
var enableCORS = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
 
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
        res.send(200);
    }
    else {
      next();
    }
};


var express = require("Express");
var url = require("url");
var http = require("http");
var app;


var port = process.argv[2];
app = express();
http.createServer(app).listen(port);

app.use(enableCORS)
```

From my website, I send a httpGet request to my Server.js (which i run in my console using node --harmony server.js 3000). This is the httpGet function:

```
function httpGet(URL) {
    var xmlHttp = null;
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET", URL, false);
    xmlHttp.send(null);

    return xmlHttp.response;
}
```

The request I send itself is:

```
var items = JSON.parse(httpGet("http://localhost:3000/items"));
```

This works fine, my console says the GET request was succesful with a 200 code. The only reason this works, is because i use the "enableCORS" function.

Now I want to create a login function, third party authentication, using Facebook.
I found this code for that purpose:

```
var passport = require('passport')
, FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;

    passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    clientSecret: FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://www.example.com/auth/facebook/callback"
},

function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    User.findOrCreate(..., function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      done(null, user);
    });
}
));

app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', 
passport.authenticate('facebook', { successRedirect: '/',
                                  failureRedirect: '/login' }));
```

However, when I send the following request:

```
httpGet("http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook");
```

I get the same CORS error. The error tells me to enable CORS or to put sender and receiver in the same domain. Since I obviously cannot get Facebook into my own domain, I'll have to enable CORS. However, as you can see above, I already enabled CORS. I also applied at the Developers section at Facebook and filled in my own App ID and App Secret, so that can't be the error. It actually sends the request to Facebook/Oauth with my ID and App Secret, but CORS is simply blocking it. What is causing this error?

Comment: You are misunderstanding CORS .... the access header has to be in the remote server header. Setting it on your server to make request to facebook does nothing

Comment: @charlietfl Which server is the remote server? Isn't that facebook? Because as far as I know, there are 3 parties:
My website (a html/js file), my local server(a js file) running on my terminal, and facebook.

Comment: @SQLApprentice: Yes, the facebook server. Facebook need to allow your application to make an XMLHttpRequest without triggring same-origin-policy. CORS is that mechanism.. for Facebook, not for you. If Facebook doesn't allow you via CORS you can't use CORS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Faced the same error when using passport for facebook login.

What I think is happening is, passport sends a 302 redirection back to the client. But since the request is happening over XMLHttpRequest, facebook rejects the redirected request as it came from another domain.

Therefore, I resorted to doing window.location.href = '/auth/facebook' instead of making an XMLHttpRequest.

Hope this helps

P.S: Wanted to comment but was not able to as I need certain minimum reputation